# apache solr delete-copy-field

Tags: solr, schema

I have created a copy field. but now i want to delete it. Solr is throwing an error ie.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "errors":[{
      "delete-copy-field":{
        "source":"*assignees",
        "dest":"all_assignees"},
      "errorMessages":["No such operation : delete-copy-field"]}]}
```

I m using solr-5-0-0.

I using the command:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "delete-copy-field":{ "source":"*assignees", "dest":"all_assignees" }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/<<core name>>/schema
```

The copy field exists. i hav chked it using this command:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8983/solr/patentCore/schema/copyfields
```

I have looked at the official document of solr. I am doing exactly the same thing mentioned in the document.

Please suggest what could be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was added in Solr 5.1.0, so you will need to upgrade your Solr version.